# Do heat pump water heaters need to connect to outside for any reason?

Tags: water, heater, pump, heat

My roommate is considering a heat pump water heater, but the HOA doesn't allow a lot of connections on the outside of the house, so we were wondering what connections are necessary. I heard it's better to have air intake/exhaust hooked up to the outdoors if possible in order to prevent the heat exchanger from getting gunked up so fast.

But if we just use nasty air from the garage, then is it easy to clean the heat exchanger off?

Is there any other part that needs to connect to outside the house?

Thank you!

Comment: I guarantee you that every house in your HOA Nazi neighborhood has at least one AC/heat pump sitting in the back or side yard. Yours does too. Go look at the line sets connected to them. That's what your HPWH will need. Do be aware that the HPWP will take heat from wherever it's installed. If that's in the house/garage, it's taking heat from the air that you've paid to heat with some other method, so you're really using your house HVAC system to heat your water, too.

Comment: Is your current water heater in a closet in the garage? What type (gas or electric, tank or tankless) and size (in gal or liters) is your current water heater?

Comment: Where is this--country, state, city?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the good questions. Let me add more detail. We live in a unique place where the houses are "connected". It The garage is in the front of the house, and we cannot run pipes out of the side of the garage to the back yard because on the left the house shares a wall with the neighbor's house (with no space in between) and on the right side is the "front facing" area, which the HOA will not allow us to run pipes out of. 

WE DO NOT HAVE ANY GAS LINES IN THE HOUSING COMPLEX. EVERYTHING IS ELECTRIC. So the only intake/exhaust would be into the garage.

Comment: This is in California btw. We do not pay to heat the garage (at least not intentionally.) The garage gets super hot in the summer, but not super cold in the winter. I don't think it would be a problem if a heat pump was removing heat from the garage (as a matter of fact it might be helpful!) The main issue I've read about with having the heat pump air intake/exhaust in the garage is that it's using dirty/dusty air so I would need to clean off the heat exchanger. I'm wondering if a HPWH is viable in this situation and if so how easy is it to clean off the heat exchanger? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

My heat pump water heater is in the garage, and has two small connections to the outside - the temperature and pressure (T&P) relief valve drain, and the condensate drain.  Both are small (3/4" or so) pipes.

The filter gets gunked up, but is very easy to clean.  I just take it out and rinse it off in the sink.

Answer (score 2):

A heat pump water heater with the compressor on top of the tank chills its surroundings so it must be in a large enough room that the room will not get too cold. It cannot be placed in a tight closet unless there is ventilation from a warmer space or from outdoors.

In a hot climate this chilling effect is free a/c if it can be ducted out to the living space.

There is a new type of heat pump water heater called a split system. The compressor unit is outside just like the condensing unit of central a/c. Water is heated in the outside unit and piped to a storage tank inside which can last for >50 years if it made from stainless steel or other durable material. The drawback is the initial price of the split system is very high.

EDIT

A garage is a large enough room that a heat pump water heater won't chill it excessively. Even a large laundry room would probably accomodate a heat pump water heater. What is your current arrangement?

https://youtu.be/omivdhxdGv0

Comment: Yeah, you gotta watch that chilling effect.  They installed a heat pump water heater in the Florida state house, unfortunately they put it in the same room with free speech rights :)